# How to solve Xaml Parse Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

I downloaded the **Wox launcher** project from [git](https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox)
Getting **XamlParseException** in App.Xaml and Additional information: 'Set property '**System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source**' threw an exceptionLine number '9' and line position '18'..

Is it beceause of different processor?
The code in the App.Xaml file is

```
<Application x:Class="Wox.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
         Startup="OnStartup">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/Dark.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Languages/en.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi70H.png)
**InnerException:** 
       HResult=-2147024893
       **Message=Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Themes\Dark.xaml'.**
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
            at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.ContentFilePart.CriticalOpenFile(String filename)
            at MS.Internal.AppModel.ContentFilePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
            at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
            at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetContentType(WebResponse response)
            at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponseStream(WebRequest request, ContentType& contentType)
            at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<>c.b__342_0(Object target, Object value)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
       **InnerException:**

Comment: Is there a nested exception giving more detail? Are you sure the `Dark.xaml` file is present?

Comment: Yah the file is there.  Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.

Comment: No, I'd expect there to be additional information about *what exception was thrown by the setter*. It should be there as an InnerException.

Comment: project is here https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox

Comment: Yes, you've shown that already - but I was asking what the inner exception in the exception being thrown was.

Comment: I am sorry i don't know how to find the inner exception details.I have added the screen shot of the exception msg.

Comment: Its not that hard... in your screenshot, there are two interesting links given by visual studio that you can use: "Copy exception details to clipboard" (and paste the result into a text editor) and "View Details..." (and navigate to the `InnerException` property until it is `null`)

Comment: hope i added the InnerException details

Comment: Hi i was kept my project folder inside another.After i moved it out and now i am not getting that error.Thank you very much for your help.